# Make An identifier or keyword follow a numeric identifier react - rapid api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numeric, identifier, rapidapi

I try to use the coinranking api from rapid api but i get a error when a i went to display the 24h volume of a cryptocurrency.

the data is display like this:

```
  Object
    data:
     coin:
      24hVolume: "21504479215"
     allTimeHigh: {price: '68763.41083248306', timestamp: 1636502400}
```

but when i type cryptoDetails?.coin.24hVolume

I got a error that say: An identifier or keyword does not follow a numeric identifier.

How i can override this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric identifiers are [not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Identifier_after_number) in JavaScript. However, you could access to object properties using [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation).

> In the object[property_name] syntax, the property_name is just a string or Symbol. So, it can be any string, including '1foo', '!bar!', or even ' ' (a space).

Like this.

```js
obj.data.coin['24hVolume']
```